# Rails 4 and Template reserved word

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates

I have a Rails 4 application and I have created a Template model. I've got a problem when I try to fetch some data from that model in a view, for example:

```
<%= Template.where(:key_name => 'email_layout').first.content %>
```

It says:

```
ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `where' for ActionView::Template:Class
```

What can I do?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just use

```
 ::Template.where(....)
```

and Rails will find the correct model.

Comment: You know you shouldn't be querying the database in the view, right? This belongs in the controller or model. Glad I could help!

Comment: I know I shouldn't, but this time i needed to. Thank u.